# jQuery UI tabs disable tab navigation

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I tried to disable tab navigation using

```
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) { return false; }
});
```

However, this also disables the flow links I'm using for navigation:

```
$('input.nexttab').click(function() {
    var tab_num = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
    // error check this tab before proceeding
    if ( check_tab(tab_num) ) {
        $tabs.tabs('select', tab_num + 1 );
    }
});
```

Ideally, I'd want to disable tab navigation for tabs to right of current tab, and ensure my <<prev and next>> tab navigation buttons always work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried setting the [event option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-event) to something that isn't likely to be fired (if at all)?

For instance:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({ event: 'change' });
```

or

```
$('#tabs').tabs({ event: '' }); //probably better
```

Comment: +1 setting it to onchange works fine, empty doesn't though.  Odds are that the tab control won't fire an onchange anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should store a flag on the first closure, in the function you pass to `$(document).ready`, set it true when your next/prev buttons are clicked, and set back to false when the tab has been shown, by doing so, you will be only able to change tab by using the buttons.

Check [this working sample](http://jsbin.com/emiko/edit) and the following code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var allowTabChange = false; 
  var $myTabs = $("#tabs"); 

  $myTabs.tabs({ 
                    select: function(event, ui) { return allowTabChange; }, 
                    show: function(event, ui) { allowTabChange = false; }, 
               }); 

  $('#nextButton').click(function(){offsetTab(1);}); 
  $('#prevButton').click(function(){offsetTab(-1);}); 

  // Helper functions

  function offsetTab(offset){ 
    var tab_num = $myTabs.tabs('option', 'selected'); 
    var nextTab = tab_num + offset; 

    if ( check_tab(nextTab) ) { 
      allowTabChange = true; 
      $myTabs.tabs('select', nextTab); 
    } 
  }

  function check_tab(tab_num){        
    return tab_num >= 0 && tab_num < $myTabs.tabs('length'); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Hmmmm, seems a little messy - I was hoping there's would be a one liner to easily add/remove the event handler from the tabs. I could live with all tabs being disabled as long as the prev/next links work (to simplify the logic). Use a selector on the .ui-tabs-nav class elements and delete the click event? Would that work?