# jquery library for tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, tabs

Please suggest the jquery library for tab function. I used jquery-1.6.4.min.js,jquery jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js and jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.css .But not it works. I want to disable the tab on ready function.
My code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("#tabs1").tabs({
        disabled: true
    });

});
```

error got d.disabled.concat is not a function (in jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js)

any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
.tabs('disable', tabId) //disables a specific tab within the set
```

for more see:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-does-tabs-disable-do
[jQuery UI tabs disable tab navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113023/jquery-ui-tabs-disable-tab-navigation)

Comment: There are more option see a link.Its my bad luck.same code work for me not for you.:(

Comment: i used $("#tabs1").tabs('disable', '#tabs1-1'); tabs1-1 is first sub tag of tabs1

Comment: if links and ans helps you to solve your problem accept the ans D :).

Answer (score 0):

I am actually using `<li id="disabled"><a href="#">Tab name</a></li>` with 1.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of tab management..

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li id="li1"><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
    <li id="li2"><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
    <li id="li3"><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabdata">

 <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">tab content for 1</div>
 <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">tab content for 2</div>
 <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">tab content for 3</div>
</div>

  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active'); //Remove any 'active' class
        $(this).addClass('active'); //Add 'active' class to selected tab
        $('.tab_content').hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn('fast'); //Fade in the active content

        return false;
    });


Some css

 ul.tabs {
            padding: 0;
            float: left;
            list-style: none;
            height: 25px;
            padding-left:5px;

        }
        ul.tabs li {
            float: left;
            margin-right:1px;
            margin-top:3px;
            padding: 0;
            width:155px;
            height:19px;
            float:left;

        }
        ul.tabs li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #37173b;
            display: block;
            font:  normal 13px arial;
            outline: none;
            text-align:center;
            line-height:21px;
        }
```

Comment: actualy my tab working smoothly except disable when loading. I need this tabs disable when loading and enable the click event of particular button like save button

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by

```
$('#tabs1-1 :input').attr('disabled', true);  //'tabs1-1' is first div in 'tabs1' div
```